# Rails 3 dynamic form errors in boostrap 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm using [#403 dynamic forms Railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms) combined with twitter-boostrap-rails 3 and simpleform gems. I have some custom validations for the dynamic form. For example when one field its empty I use:

```
self.errors.add field, "can't be blank"
```

This is error can be showed iterating over object.errors.full_messages. The problem its than boostrap 3 doesn't add the proper css and doen't add the text field can't be blank under the input.
What can be causing this issue?

I think there is a problem with simple-form picking the dynamic inputs because with the ones that are not dynamic it works!

Comment: Are you calling `f.error :field_name` in the template or included it in wrapper definition in initializers?

Comment: I didn't find it the initializers. In the template do you mean in the view? Yes it is in the view.